# DOMPDF 0.5.1 - new server environment breaks PDF output formatting

Tags: php, pdf, symfony1, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to generate PDFs inside of a symfony application.

On my current production server, it works great.  I was tasked with moving
it to a new server.  I checked out the code on the new server, and while it does generate a PDF still, most of the formatting is broken.

Here's an example of what happens:
http://geoffreymaddock.com/work/project-dompdf-working.jpg
http://geoffreymaddock.com/work/project-dompdf-broken.jpg

Some of the formatting works on the new server, some does not.

Both servers have identical code.  They both run php 5.1.6.

The only difference that I can really see is that there are extra php modules installed on the new server.  I'm not sure what could be causing this issue though.

Working server modules:
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
ldap
libxml
mime_magic
mssql
mysql
mysqli
oci8
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
posix
pspell
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

New server modules:

[PHP Modules]
apc
bcmath
bz2
calendar
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mime_magic
mssql
mysql
mysqli
ncurses
oci8
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_OCI
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
phpcups
posix
pspell
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
SQLite
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

Anyone run into this before, or know of specific conflicts?

Comment: Where's the font coming from? It looks like it's being rendered as having zero line height on the new server FSR.

Comment: There are inline styles that provide the font css.  It definitely looks like the line heights are rendering as zero.  I confirmed that the HTML that is passed to the DOMPDF class is identical on both servers.

Comment: @GeoffMaddock what exact version of dompdf do you run in php 5.1.6? in my server php 5.1.6 I get an error because it tells me that dompdf is not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

dompdf_font_family_cache

Contained static paths for font locations on the original server which broke
on the new server.  Took a long time to figure that out, but glad I did.